# Slow rendering of image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, react-redux, lazy-loading

I have this kind of UI

[image: sample]

So when you click on some of the vertical small tiles it changes the src of the big image. And when that happen my image is so slowly rendered. Yes, I use big image here but for the testing purposes. I think I should handle this case too and show the image when it is completely ready to be displayed.

This is some code examples:

**Vertical component**

```
<div>
    {images.map((img, index) => ( //images are coming from props
      <Button onClick={() => handleImageChange(index)}>
         <Img src={img}/>
       </Button>
    ))}
</div>
```

**Horizontal component**

```
<div>
   {images.length ? ( //images coming from props
      <Img src={images[activeImageIndex]}/>
   ) : (
      <Skeleton variant="rect" animation="wave"/>
   )}
</div>
```

And the on click event of those tiles just changes the index from 0 to 1 for example and takes images[index] to display it.

```
const activeImageIndex = useSelector((state) => state.gdp.activeImageIndex);
const handleImageChange = (index) => {
  dispatch(setActiveImageIndex(index));
};
```

So the question is how can I display the image when it is ready completely?

PS: I am using react-image for Img component

Comment: You might want to check out something like https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash which will create small placeholder images until the image loads

Comment: See also: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/

Comment: All good. But I tried to listen to onload of the image and it is triggering and then the image starts to pain slowly. So it's not working